# Stalk of the product or power of quasi-coherent ideal sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be a Noetherian scheme. Let $\mathfrak I$ and $ \mathcal J$ be two quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals on $X$.

Is it true that for every $x\in X$, we have $(\mathfrak I \mathcal J)_x=\mathfrak I_x \mathcal J_x$ ?

If this is not true in general, do we at least have that for every $x \in X$ and every integer $n>0$, that $(\mathcal J_x)^n =(\mathcal J^n)_x $ ?

Comment: What definition precisely are you using for the product of quasi-coherent sheaves of ideals?  I can think of a couple possibilities, one which would work for general sheaves of ideals, and another which would involve gluing $\tilde I \cdot \tilde J := (IJ) \tilde{~}$ on affine open subsets.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler: I thought there was a standard definition for product of ideal sheaves , I mean Stacks project, Eisenbud's Geometry of Schemes book and other references uses product of ideal sheaf all the time ... isn't it just the sheaf associated to the presheaf $U \to \mathfrak I (U) \mathcal J(U) $ ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Fix $f \in \mathscr{O}_{X,x}$.  Then if $f \in (\mathfrak{I}\mathfrak{J})_x$, that means that for some open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, $f \in \mathfrak{I}(U)\mathfrak{J}(U)$.  Suppose $f = \sum_{i=1}^n g_i h_i$ with $g_i \in \mathfrak{I}(U), h_i \in \mathfrak{J}(U)$; then each $g_i \in \mathfrak{I}_x$ and each $h_i \in \mathfrak{J}_x$ so $f \in \mathfrak{I}_x \mathfrak{J}_x$.

Conversely, if $f \in \mathfrak{I}_x \mathfrak{J}_x$, suppose $f = \sum_{i=1}^n g_i h_i$ with each $g_i \in \mathfrak{I}_x$ and $h_i \in \mathfrak{J}_x$.  Since there is a finite number of terms, there is some open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that each $g_i \in \mathfrak{I}(U)$ and each $h_i \in \mathfrak{J}(U)$.  It follows that $f \in \mathfrak{I}\mathfrak{J}(U)$, so $f \in (\mathfrak{I}\mathfrak{J})_x$.

Comment: This proof works for $X$ any ringed space, right? No need to ask $X$ to be a Noetherian scheme, if I have understood the proof well.